# Syntax for solving a parametric differential equation (density function in expression)

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation with a parameter $\mu$

$ \frac{dg(\delta) }{d \delta}= \frac{{w\delta {f_D}(\delta )\left( {1 - \mu {F_R}(g(\delta ))} \right)}}{{1 + \mu \delta {f_R}(g(\delta ))w\left( {{F_D}(\delta ) - 1} \right)}}$

which includes $F'_D\equiv f_D$ that characterizes RV $D$, same for RV $R$

I want a particular solution with
$$w=1$$
$$F_D,F_R\sim u[0,1]$$

when I plug pdf and cdf manually everything works beautifully, i.e

```
eps = 0;
s = 1;
alp = 1;
W = 1;
ODE = Derivative[1][g][d] == -((
    d (-W (1/(s - eps)) + M W (g[d]/(alp*s)) (1/(s - eps))))/(
    1 - d M W (1/(alp*s)) + d M W ((d - eps)/(s - eps)) (1/(alp*s))));
ODECON = g[eps] == 0;
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ODE, ODECON}, g, {d, eps, s}, {M}];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[M][d], {M, 0, 1}]], {d, eps, s}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"d", "g[d]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"mu=0", "mu=1"}]
```

The code gives me data point that I plot with latex's tikz get this

[image]

A problem arises when I'm trying to use a build in function for cdf.

```
eps = 0;
s = 1;
alp = 1;
W = 1;
Fd[x_] := CDF[UniformDistribution[{eps, s}], x];
Fr[x_] := CDF[UniformDistribution[{0, alp*s}], x];
ODE = Derivative[1][g][d] == -((
    d (-W Derivative[1][Fd][d] + M W Fr[g[d]] Derivative[1][Fd][d]))/(
    1 - d M W Derivative[1][Fr][g[d]] + 
     d M W Fd[d] Derivative[1][Fr][g[d]]));
ODECON = g[eps] == 0;
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ODE, ODECON}, g, {d, eps, s}, {M}];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[M][d], {M, 0, 1}]], {d, eps, s}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"d", "g[d]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"mu=0", "mu=1"}]
```

The error is

```
ParametricNDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at d == 0.`.
```

I realize that the problem is that build-in function is piecewise and that causes an error. What would be the most elegant way to resolve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest workaround for the current setting might be to define `Fd[x_] := x; Fr[x_] := x/alp;`. However, one has to be very cautious with `Fr`: If `g[d]` crosses the boundary of the interval $[0,\alpha]$, then `Derivative[1][Fr][g[d]]` should be treated as Dirac-delta distribution (with  prefactor depending on the step size) and things might get quite messy. Many cases can be handled by `WhenEvent` but I am not sure how this would work for your very nonlinear right hand side of the ODE. I even don't know if this case may orccur.

Comment: Thank you Henrik, appreciate your comment. I guess I can just simply do everything manually how I did earlier.

Comment: Ah right, you did it already. The problem with derivatives of discontinuous functions is that it really depends on what you model. For example, you probably don't want to have Dirac-deltas for `Fd` at the boundary of the unit interval. So Mathematice is right to be rather conservative about warning the user.